# What's the exact purpose of Yii Appliance?

Tags: yii, appliance

It's introduction is here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/

But what's that virtual server image for ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to have a preconfigured server environment with the software in question already installed, configured, and ready to run.

Comment: Oh,the usage is very limited then,means nothing for most users.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dav, also, it is not updated very often (If I'm not bad, the included Yii version is 1.0.2 and current is 1.1.2, about 1 year old). Y recommend you to download the last stable version and try with it with your own web server it can be a local server). If you have Windows OS I recommend WAMP (one of the easiest to install) or ZWAMP (I think this is the most updated one, http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/), if you are using Linux or *BSD you have more and easy-to-install alternatives.